# Azure cmdlet Remove-AzureDedicatedCircuit error

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to drop an ExpressRoute circuit which has been created in Azure.

The circuit is currently in status "NotProvisioned", and was created using the 'New-AzureDedicatedCircuit' cmdlet, and a ServiceKey obtained.

Due to a misconfiguration of the bandwidth option, we want to delete the circuit, and I am attempting to use the 'Remove-AzureDedicatedCircuit' cmdlet, however it is erroring out.

Syntax:

```
Remove-AzureDedicatedCircuit -ServiceKey "my_service_key_string_here"
```

The received error is:

```
Remove-AzureDedicatedCircuit : MissingOrIncorrectVersionHeader: Request needs to have a x-ms-version header.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AzureDedicatedCircuit -ServiceKey 6c6af1af-0eb2-4f18-961c-b9ccdf8d50a2 -F ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzureDedicatedCircuit], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ExpressRoute.RemoveAzureDedicatedCircuitCommand
```

I have tried running with the -Force option, but this merely removes the confirmation dialogue. The -Debug option provides more information around the REST API calls made by the cmdlet:

```
DEBUG: 14:20:52 - RemoveAzureDedicatedCircuitCommand begin processing with ParameterSet '__AllParameterSets'.
DEBUG: 14:20:56 - using account id '<redacted_my_azure_ID>'...
DEBUG: ============================ HTTP REQUEST ============================

HTTP Method:
DELETE

Absolute Uri:
https://management.core.windows.net/<redacted_Azure_subscription_ID>/services/networking/dedicatedcircuits/<redacted_circuit_ServiceKey>?api-version=1.0

Headers:

Body:



DEBUG: ============================ HTTP RESPONSE ============================

Status Code:
BadRequest

Headers:
Date                          : Tue, 17 Feb 2015 14:21:13 GMT
Server                        : Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

Body:
<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Code>MissingOrIncorrectVersionHeader</Code>
  <Message>Request needs to have a x-ms-version header.</Message>
</Error>
```

I'm starting to think there's a cmdlet bug.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: So this is a confirmed bug, also seen in the set-azurebgppeering cmdlet. Apparently the ExpressRoute powershell module is still officially Beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install previous version. I used Azure PowerShell v8.14, removed it and installed 8.13 from https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases. It solved the problem.

Comment: Finding a colleague with an earlier version proved successful - we managed to achieve the required running 8.12. I've raised it with MS.